# Is my hard drive failing? Win 10 won't boot

Tags: windows-10, diagnostic, hard-drive-failure

My son's Windows 10 laptop won't boot, laptop fell a couple feet while powered up but booted fine right after that. A couple hours later it wouldn't boot, and got stuck after a few seconds on the Win10 startup error recovery page, and all attempts at using embedded Windows recovery tools didn't change anything.

I was able to boot a live Linux DVD and copy off important data, but before reformatting and installing Windows again, I looked at the SMART data and saw a few things that bothered me...

Is the drive bad and it should it be replaced? It's only 3 months old but shows 552 bad sectors which seems excessive...

[image: HD Info Page 1]

[image: HD Info Page 2]

Comment: Based on the answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/657454/393570), 552 bad sectors is not excessive.

Comment: No offense, but that answer just throws out a bunch of numbers and doesn't say how many sectors being bad is excessive or normal. For comparison, my 6 year old desktop PC with the original 1TB HDD has ONE bad sector and has been powered on 4 years, 4 months,  and 17 days.

Comment: It is still under 1% of available sectors.

Comment: Yes, it is under 1% of available sectors, but I've never heard of that being a rule. Google results are all over on this topic, some say any amount of bad sectors is cause for drive replacement, some say 10, etc. Guess I was looking for something more concrete.

Comment: Hmm... Now it says 248 bad sectors?!?! Did a wipe of all partitions and clean install of Windows and it has half the bad sectors... odd.

Comment: OK, now I am really puzzled... the drive shows zero bad sectors in SMART diagnostics and that it is completely healthy. Weird.

Comment: Everybody seems to have missed the salient issue… a) if the data is mission-critical & you have a backup, bin the drive & buy another. b) If it's not, & you have a backup, use it til it fails. c) If it's failed already, back to a). d) if you have no backup...

Comment: @Tetsujin True enough... All data has been recovered and this is a college students PC that is 5 years old. I am still reloading the PC but I bought him a new laptop on special yesterday.  So it is, or soon will be, just a shelved spare.